# Implicit type conversion constant vs variables

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have faced a situation where I have some integer value in a **constant** and multiplying it with **math.Pi** constant as below:

```
func main() {
    const a = 5
    fmt.Printf("%v", a*math.Pi)
}
```

On execution it gives following result:

```
15.707963267948966
```

But, when I change the **constant to variable (`variable a`)** as below:

```
func main() {
    a := 5
    fmt.Printf("%v", a*math.Pi)
}
```

On compilation it gives the following error:

```
constant 3.14159 truncated to integer
```

As far as I understand implicit numeric type conversion is working when all operands of expression are constants, but not working when any of these a variable.

**But why is this happening?**

Comment: That is how the language is _defined_. In Go you _cannot_ multiply a int (a) and a float. Your a is an int and math.Pi is a float. Just read the spec. Different ruels apply for consts and for variables. That's all there is to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because of Go's *untyped constants*. In both cases, you are not explicitly specifying a type.

In the first case, you are defining an untyped constant (you could also define a typed constant by using `const a float64 = 5`). For an untyped constant, a type will only be inferred when it’s used in a context that requires a type – i.e. when you are multiplying it with math.Pi, the compiler will "guess" that you want to have a float there, and everything works fine.

In the second case, a variable of course has to have a type, so the type inference takes place when declaring the variable, and since you used "5", the compiler will "infer" int, and multiplying an int and a float is not possible in Go. You could use e.g. `a:=5.0` or `var a float64 = 5` to declare a as a float64, then this code would work as well.

See [this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/constants) for more details.